# Forming an array format for multi row insertion nodejs-mysql

Tags: javascript, mysql, arrays, node.js

I have an object item like below

```
var item = {"9":"9","22":"22","23":"23","24":"24"};
```

and variables `var cart = 23;` and `var group = 40;`

Now I want to form those items in a format such that I can perform multi-row MySQL insert like below

```
var sql = "INSERT INTO test (item, cart, group) VALUES ?";
var values = [
    [9, 23, 40],
    [22, 23, 40],
    [23, 23, 40],
    [24, 23, 40]
];
```

I need to form the above array format to perform multi rows insert in node js. How to make the above format?

Comment: do you need the key or value?

Comment: `values` of item object. I want to make that `values` array format

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could map the values of the object and return an array with numbers.

```js
var item = { 9: "9", 22: "22", 23: "23", 24:"24" },
    cart = 23,
    group = 40,
    array = Object.keys(item).map(function (k) {
        return [+item[k], cart, group];
    });
    
console.log(array);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [Array.prototype.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map):

```
var values = Object.keys(item).map(k => [k, cart, group]);
```